# Why does it give me an error. it's unknown C++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ . The program doesn't compile i am using Xcode. It doesn't give me any error. It just doesn't compile which's weird. Thanks for the help! 
I am using 3 files as you can  see.  I think. there's a problem with the implementation that i can not figure out, if you have any suggestion for a better IDE that Xcode than would be helpful. 
Thanks again
Car.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;


void Car:: setMaker(string m)
{
    maker=m;
}
string Car:: getMaker()
{
    return maker;
}
void Car:: setModel(int m)
{
    model=m;
}
int Car:: getModel()
{
    return model;
}
```

Car.h

```
#ifndef _CAR_H;
#define _CAR_H;
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
private:
    string maker;
    int model;
public:
    void setMaker(string m);
    string getMaker();
    void setModel(int m);
    int getModel();

};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.cpp"
#include "Car.h"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    Car c1;
    c1.setMaker("BMW");
    c1.getMaker();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include "Car.cpp"` you should never do that. This should cause linker errors.

Comment: @drescherjm yeah, it just worked! why that matters tho? thanks!!

Comment: I expect you multiple defined errors because car.cpp was being compiled 2 times into your executable.

Comment: @lurker i meant it doesn't say where the error is. lol!

Comment: How to correctly compile a C++ program made up of multiple files should be fully explained in every C++ textbook. Your C++ textbook should also have a pretty good explanation of how `#include` works, what it means, and what it does. Is there anything specific about the explanations in your C++ textbook which is unclear to you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I actually don't like using textbooks! so far so good. thanks!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_CAR_H`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. You will not be able to fully learn and understanding anything except the most basic aspects of C++ without the benefit fo a good textbook that provides a guided, methodical introduction to C++'s advanced topics. Good luck learning and understand templates, template specialization, variadic templates, virtual inheritence, containers, iterators, algorithms, multithreading and synchronization, without a textbook.